# Nested queries and using temp tables to make them more readable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a select query it has a lot of joins and it has 5 inner queries.

When using nested queries it will look like

```
Query(NestedQuery1(NestedQuery2(NestedQuery3(NestedQuery4(NestedQuery5)as C)as M)as X)as D)
```

and it gets really messy...

On the other hand I could do it like

```
NestedQuery5 INTO #C
NestedQuery4 INTO #M From #C 
.
.
.
Query From D
```

My question is which one would you go with nested or using temp tables? Neither is not an option

p.s I am a noob with less than a week experience in SQL, but the query is working fine whether I am using the first method or the second one.

```
/*set period*/
DECLARE @DATE1 DATETIME 
SET @DATE1 ='01.01.2000' 
DECLARE @DATE2 DATETIME 
SET @DATE2 = '01.01.2050' 

SELECT contactid, 
       country, 
       city, 
       itemsbought, 
       lastlogindate, 
       email, 
       lastbuydate, 
       openscount, 
       clickscount, 
       newslettersrecived, 
       averagereadtime, 
       lastnewsletterdate, 
       menge                                        'BuyCount', 
       ( Rank() 
           OVER ( 
             ORDER BY menge DESC) )                 mengeRank, 
       ekavg                                        'EKØ', 
       ( Rank() 
           OVER ( 
             ORDER BY ekavg DESC) )                 ekavgRank, 
       ekt                                          'EKTotal', 
       ( Rank() 
           OVER ( 
             ORDER BY ekt DESC) )                   ektRank, 
       vkavg                                        'VKØ', 
       ( Rank() 
           OVER ( 
             ORDER BY vkavg DESC) )                 vkavgRank, 
       vkt                                          'VKTotal', 
       ( Rank() 
           OVER ( 
             ORDER BY vkt DESC) )                   vktRank, 
       XS.margent / XS.menge                        'MargenØ', 
       ( Rank() 
           OVER ( 
             ORDER BY XS.margent / XS.menge DESC) ) MarginAVGRank, 
       margent                                      'MargenTotal', 
       ( Rank() 
           OVER ( 
             ORDER BY margent DESC) )               margentotalRank, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Isnull(vkt, 0) != 0 
              AND Isnull(menge, 0) > 1 THEN ( ( vkt - ekt ) / vkt ) * 100 
         ELSE 0 
       END                                          AS 'Margen%' 
FROM   (SELECT RR.*, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN Isnull(menge, 0) != 0 THEN ekt / menge 
                 ELSE NULL 
               END       AS EKAVG, 
               vkt - ekt MargenT, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN Isnull(menge, 0) != 0 THEN vkt / menge 
                 ELSE NULL 
               END       AS VKAVG 
        FROM   (SELECT Max(orderdate) lastbuydate, 
                       itemsbought, 
                       contactid, 
                       country, 
                       city, 
                       email, 
                       lastlogindate, 
                       Sum(menge)     Menge, 
                       Sum(ek)        EKT, 
                       Sum(vk)        VKT 
                FROM   (SELECT AA.*, 
                               menge * Isnull(ekprice, 0) 
                               AS EK, 
                               ( Isnull(unitprice, 0) / producttotal ) * 
                               Isnull(otax, 0) 
                                       otaxamount, 
                               ( Isnull(unitprice, 0) / producttotal ) * Isnull( 
                               odiscount, 0) 
                                       discountamount, 
                               ( Isnull(unitprice, 0) / producttotal ) * 
                               Isnull(coupondiscount, 0) 
                                       coupondiscountamount, 
                               menge * ( Isnull(unitprice, 0) - ( 
                                         Isnull(unitprice, 0) / producttotal ) 
                                                                * 
                                                                Isnull(otax, 0) 
                                         - ( Isnull(unitprice, 0) / producttotal 
                                           ) * 
                                           Isnull(odiscount, 0) - 
                                         ( 
                                         Isnull( 
                                                 unitprice, 0) / producttotal ) 
                                         * 
                                         Isnull( 
                                         coupondiscount 
                                         , 0) 
                                       ) 
                               AS VK 
                        FROM   (SELECT i.catalogid, 
                                       c.contactid, 
                                       c.city, 
                                       c.country, 
                                       c.firstname, 
                                       c.lastname, 
                                       c.email, 
                                       c.lastlogindate, 
                                       i.supplierid, 
                                       p.cname, 
                                       i.ekprice, 
                                       i.unitprice, 
                                       o.odate, 
                                       o.otax, 
                                       o.odiscount, 
                                       o.oshipcost, 
                                       o.coupondiscount, 
                                       o.producttotal, 
                                       s.name, 
                                       Stuff((SELECT 
                                       ',' 
                                       + COALESCE(Ltrim(Rtrim(i.catalogid)), '') 
                                              FROM   orders o 
                                                     INNER JOIN oitems i 
                                                             ON o.orderid = 
                                                                i.orderid 
                                              WHERE  o.ocustomerid = c.contactid 
                                              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS 
                                       ItemsBought, 
                                       CASE WHEN o.oshippeddate BETWEEN @Date1 
                                       AND 
                                       @Date2 THEN 
                                       Isnull(i.f2, 0) 
                                               ELSE 0 
                                       END + CASE WHEN o.oshippeddate2 BETWEEN 
                                       @Date1 
                                       AND 
                                       @Date2 THEN 
                                               Isnull(i.f3, 0) 
                                       ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN o.oshippeddate3 
                                       BETWEEN 
                                       @Date1 
                                       AND @Date2 
                                       THEN 
                                       Isnull(i.f4, 0) ELSE 0 END          AS 
                                       Menge, 
                                       CASE 
                                         WHEN o.oshippeddate IS NOT NULL 
                                               OR o.oshippeddate2 IS NOT NULL 
                                               OR o.oshippeddate3 IS NOT NULL 
                                       THEN 
                                         odate 
                                         ELSE NULL 
                                       END                                 AS 
                                       orderdate 
                                FROM   orders o 
                                       INNER JOIN oitems i 
                                               ON i.orderid = o.orderid 
                                       LEFT OUTER JOIN products p 
                                                    ON i.catalogid = p.catalogid 
                                       LEFT OUTER JOIN suppliers s 
                                                    ON 
                                       i.supplierid = s.supplierid 
                                       RIGHT OUTER JOIN customers c 
                                                     ON 
                                       o.ocustomerid = c.contactid)AS 
                               AA) T 
                GROUP  BY T.contactid, 
                          T.email, 
                          T.itemsbought, 
                          T.country, 
                          T.lastlogindate, 
                          T.city) AS RR 
        GROUP  BY RR.ekt, 
                  RR.menge, 
                  RR.vkt, 
                  RR.country, 
                  RR.lastlogindate, 
                  RR.contactid, 
                  RR.itemsbought, 
                  RR.city, 
                  RR.email, 
                  RR.lastbuydate) XS 
       INNER JOIN customerstatistics cst 
               ON XS.contactid = cst.id 
ORDER  BY buycount
```

Comment: You can also use common table expressions to "modularize" your query

Comment: You say you are a noob on the hand, yet you have written five levels deep of subqueries on the other. In my experience, that typically means you are overcomplicating things. I'd go for option 3: refactor the query. To avoid a hypothetical discussion, how about publishing some real code here?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but isn't the nested one most performant no matter what?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name because i am a noob, not sure though

Comment: @Ruud first i wrote it using the temp table method, the made them nested!

Comment: Please show me your queries; I may be able to use it as an example to explain to you why 4 temp tables, as well as 5 nested subqueries, is just too much.

Comment: @Ruud here you go! sorry if its looks stupid to you but it gives me the expected result and its fast tested with about 60 000 records, i only know the basic features of ms sql not used to anything other than select and join, group by and order by

Comment: @Ruud did looking at that query hurt your feelings?

Comment: It's pretty big, so I need more time. Let me start by saying that it does not look stupid; from what I've seen, this is actually very good.

Comment: Having derived tables within derived tables etc will throw off the execution plan optimizer. The less deep your query is the better. Also using CTE's will definitely not help you with performance: read [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/whats-the-difference-between-a-cte-and-a-temp-table/13117#13117) on the comparison between CTEs and temporary tables. My advice on deep derived tables vs temporary tables: use temporary tables.

Comment: Other than the question on deep derived tables vs temporary tables, your query certainly has other issues. A `GROUP BY` clause on 10 fields is usually an indicator of a badly constructed query. The rest I didn't even look at, it is no longer easily readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit it: you were not overcomplicating things. The statistics you seek, do require so many levels of (sub)queries.

Of course, the query would become (much) simpler if you would store intermediate values inside your transaction tables or in additional balance tables, but that means you will have to maintain redundant data, which can be nasty. It is also a matter of taste whether you find the polution of additional columns and/or tables acceptable.

One remark about the functionality. I don't know much about statistics, but it seems more logical to me to rank your results by numeric ranges rather than exact amounts; the slightest rounding difference might already cause two near-equal sales amounts not to count together for a rank.

Technically, the query looks very good to me. I did notice that in the innermost query (AA), you are retrieving more data than you really need at that point.

- No need to join *suppliers*; AFAICT, it's unused in the rest of the query.
- No need to join *customers* yet; it's data only 'bubbles through' to the uppermost level. Pass on *ocustomerid* only, then join table *customers* at the uppermost level.

Joining suppliers and customers at the innermost query has just one benefit: you can re-use the exact same query in another context to retrieve sales order details. Could be useful in an environment where bigger queries are automatically composed out of smaller ones. When it's all manual labor, then you might as well remove the *suppliers* join and move the *customers* join to the outside. It would slightly improve readability as well as performance (though you already pointed out that this currently is not an issue).

As for your original question (nesting subqueries vs. temp tables), I don't suppose it will make much of a difference. In theory, nesting subqueries is best; let the query optimizer decide what is the best strategy.

All in all, I think you are doing a great job with this.

Comment: *"In theory, nesting subqueries is best"* > No. Just no.